# Difference in features between WildFly 8.2 and WildFly 10

Tags: wildfly-8, wildfly-10

I have to document main configuration related features that are present in wildfly 10 but not in 8.2 (as we are moving from 8.2 to 10).

I am trying to find the feature documentation but all I find is admin and developer guide. To find the difference between two versions, I have to compare guides of both of these two version, which may take some time.

Can any body suggest me some faster way to do this.

Many Thanks in advance.
Rahul

Answer (score 1):

There are likely some blog posts on some highlights at [wildfly.org](https://wildfly.org). You could also run a [JIRA release notes report](https://issues.jboss.org/secure/ConfigureReport.jspa?versions=12331186&versions=12327667&sections=all&style=html&selectedProjectId=12313721&reportKey=org.jboss.labs.jira.plugin.release-notes-report-plugin%3Areleasenotes&atl_token=AQZJ-FV3A-N91S-UDEU%7Cba50cb2a8eb7d96f23294cc4edebc6d67eb107a7%7Clin&Next=Next). Other than that it just depends on what kinds of differences you're looking for.